# How do I change the filepath using Visual Studio Database Project?

Tags: sql-server, visual-studio, t-sql, database-project

```
declare @databasename varchar(50) = 'aDatabase'
declare @dbNameTimeStamp varchar(100) = 'aDatabase_20230404_0916'

declare @backupFilePathForDev varchar(max) = 'N''J:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\'
declare @backupFilePathForProd varchar(max) = 'N''K:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\'

declare @backupFilePath varchar(max) = 'N''?:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSSQL15.MSSQLSERVER\MSSQL\Backup\'
print('backup database ' + @databasename)
exec('BACKUP DATABASE [' + @databasename + '] TO  DISK = ' + @backupFilePath + @dbNameTimeStamp + '.bak'' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT,  NAME = N'''+ @databasename + '-Full Database Backup'', SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10')
insert into MaintenancedFile([filename], filetype, maintenancetype, backuptimestamp)
values(@databasename, 'db', 'backup', GETDATE())
```

The path for `@backupFilePath` is different depending on which server I deploy to.

Is there some way to change the path depending on which publish profile I use through Visual Studio Database Project?

Comment: Are these the default paths for the instance, by any chance? If so, could you make use of `SERVERPROPERTY(N'InstanceDefaultDataPath')` and `SERVERPROPERTY(N'InstanceDefaultLogPath')`?

Comment: Unfortunately, they're not.

Comment: You can create your own SQLCMD variables in the project properties and set the desired run-time value in your server-specific publish profile. Specify the SQLCMD variable in the T-SQL script.

Comment: @DanGuzman do you mind putting that as an answer? And writing out an example. I'm not too familiar with sqlcmd.

Comment: @OnTheNetAgain, I added an answer detailing my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [database project SQLCMD variables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/ssdt/database-project-settings?f1url=%3FappId%3DDev16IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(sql.data.tools.advanceddeploymentsystemdefined.dialog)%26rd%3Dtrue&view=sql-server-ver16#bkmk_sqlcmd_variables) in T-SQL scripts when values may differ by the publish action target. The desired values can be set in a publish profile or specified via command-line during publish.

1. In the VS database project IDE, select SQLCMD Variables in the database project properties and enter the variable name and a default value:

[image]

2. Specify the SQLCMD variable name enclosed in `$()` in the T-SQL script:

   declare @backupFilePath varchar(max) = N'$(BackupFilePath)'
3. Load the publish profile and specify the desired target-specific value:

[image]

4. Save the modified publish profile for future use and/or publish.

Note system-defined SQLCMD variables are also set during the publish action. You could also leverage these in your script (e.g. `DatabaseName`) without creating a user-defined SQLCMD variable.